# How do I safely prevent sql injection with Oracle using regexp_like queries

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am in an odd situation where I must prevent SQL injection with a string query using REGEXP_LIKE in Oracle.  I cannot use a prepared statement because of a performance problem.  Oracle is taking twice as long to process the query which is causing timeouts in our production environment when a prepared statement version is used.

Normally I'd use something like oracle's escape operators { and } but in this case they have meaning in a regular expression and don't seem to work.  Aside from single quotes, what would I need to guard against for a regular expression case like this?

Query example

```
SELECT * FROM table where somecolumn = 2 and regexp_like(column, '\Wmy text\W|\Wfoo\W');
```

While I've seen other questions about manual protection from sql injection, none dealing with regular expression cases like this.

Would a q escape work like this?

```
SELECT * FROM table where somecolumn = 2 and regexp_like(column, q'[\Wmy text\W|\Wfoo\W]');
```

Comment: It's impossible to be vulnerable to SQL injection unless part of the SQL is built from user-entered data. How is your query being generated? Show your code.

Comment: I can't show the code, but the actual regular expression passed in is coming from user input.  It's part of input for a filter in a reporting dashboard.

Comment: If you're passing in user input, use a bind variable. Don't concatenate it to your SQL. If you want more help than that, please show your code. Without showing your code, how can anyone help you?

Comment: I can't use a bind variable as explained.  It causes a 50% performance drop in oracle.  One query takes 8 minutes on exadata.  

The example above is a good approximation of the actual query run without a bind variable.  The input would be what's inside the second parameter to the rexexp_like above.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to write java code for me to use this rather simply what would be special considerations for a regexp_like when you can't use a bind variable.  Most sql injection examples focus around regular text fields. Since this is a regex it likely needs different characters handled

Comment: If using a bind variable causes a 50% performance hit, that's a different problem and one that is solveable without resorting to using insecure concatenation. Bottom line: if you concatenate user-entered data into your SQL query, you will be fighting a losing battle to stop sql injection.